# Bandwidth Source

Tags: bandwidth, bandwidth-throttling

Please sorry if the following question seems stupid. Otherwise direct me to the appropriate place to ask it.

My question is, the webhosting companies where do they lease/get their bandwidth from? Do they rent the bandwidth from telecommunication companies?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Typical providers include most of the the big telecoms, plus some extra names that are specific to data transit: AT&T, Cogent, Comcast, Level3, NTT, Verizon...

Note that pricing on bandwidth gets weird for large users. Most web hosts pay on a burstable billing plan (typically 95th percentile with a minimum commit), rather than flat-rate or per byte. Some really large companies that run a lot of their own infrastructure (e.g, Google) pay nothing at all for peering.

Comment: I really really appreciate your answer. I like it. thank you so much.  I have some a small question to clarify things. Do they have something like a minimum bandwidth you must rent before they do business with you?

Comment: Yes, definitely. Also keep in mind that you'll probably need a peering point as well -- they won't run cables to your house. :)